# Full height containers collapse without border — HTML & CSS

Tags: html, css, center

I'm trying to create a page with a series of 100% `.container` divs (each having its own div inside), resulting in a long single page design. However, when I remove the border from `.container`, they all collapse.

Would anyone know why this would be?

```
  .container {

        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        display: block;
        border: 1px solid salmon;

    }

html, body {

    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 10pt;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    /* overflow: hidden; */
}
```

**EDIT: I've changed the `.container` from `display:block;` to `display:inline-block;` and this has fixed the problem. Does anyone know why this could be?**

Comment: why did you set`display:inline-block;` instead of `display:block;`. `display:inline-block;` is used to display the  element on the same line ( [w3school](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp) ), but your elements are set with `width.100%;` there is a non-sense (i think). with margin-botoom you can get the same reusult: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f_vincent/MTvrY/)

Answer (score 0):

Amswer by user **splattne** on a similar question.

====

Imagine a `<span>` element inside a `<div>`. If you give the `<span>` element a height of 100px and a red border for example, it will look like this with

**display: inline**

[image: display: inline]

**display: inline-block**

[image: display: inline-block]

**display: block**

[image]

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/Mta2b/

### More Info:

**display: block** 
It will cause the `div` to force other `divs` within a container on to a new line and hence creating spaces and collapsing designs.

**display: inline-block** 
It tries to display the `div` on the same line as other `divs` but since all your `divs` have `width:100%` so they will look like one after the other vertically although they are horizontally align.